# XAP file not loading using https

Tags: .net, silverlight, iis, https, xap

I have just upgraded a silverlight 4 app to silverlight 5. The target framework used is 4.5. Onece I publish the code in IIS, it is loading fine with http. But xap file not loading properly with https. In browser screen it is showing 100% loaded. And the screen stays there forever.

Can anyone please help on this topic?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

One advice: in this case use the developper tool of your browser to track the error (F12 on IE, look at the console, there is probably an error).

The most common cause is an error calling web service differently in http/https.

Is your IIS Server well configured, is .net 4.5 installed on your server?